# How to view script output (specifically PowerShell) from a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I'm pretty new to Jenkins, so not totally clear on how to assign/read variables.

I have a jenkinsfile with a couple stages and a bunch of steps. In one of the steps, I want to run a PowerShell script but it isn't accomplishing the intent. The problem is, when I'm in Jenkins and I go to the Console Output to troubleshoot why the PowerShell script isn't working, I don't see any of the output from the powershell script, I just see this:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell (Test PowerShell Script)
[Pipeline] }
```

Here's a trimmed-down version of my code:

```
stages {  
    stage('Stage 1') {
        agent { node {
            label "Windows"
            customWorkspace "D:\\Path"
        }}
        steps {
            dir('Directory') {
                withCredentials(
                    [usernameColonPassword(
                        credentialsId: 'credential1',
                        variable: 'BasicCred'
                    )]
                ) {
                    powershell(
                        label: 'Test PowerShell Script', 
                        returnStdout: true,
                        script: 'echo Test'
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the code provided in this [Jenkins article](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/):

```
steps {
    dir('Directory') {
        withCredentials(
            [usernameColonPassword(
                credentialsId: 'credential1',
                variable: 'BasicCred'
            )]
        ) {
            def msg = powershell(
                label: 'Test PowerShell Script', 
                returnStdout: true,
                script: 'echo Test'
            )
            println msg
        }
    }
}
```

This threw an error:

```
WorkflowScript: 135: Expected a step @ line 135, column 25.
                         def msg = powershell(
                         ^
```

I also tried putting it inside a node:

```
steps {
    dir('Directory') {
        node {
            withCredentials(
                [usernameColonPassword(
                    credentialsId: 'credential1',
                    variable: 'BasicCred'
                )]
            ) {
                def msg = powershell(
                    label: 'Test PowerShell Script', 
                    returnStdout: true,
                    script: 'echo Test'
                )
                println msg
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it threw an error that the node is missing a label, and when I tried adding a label it threw another error.

So what's the right way to go about this? I just want to capture the output from the PowerShell script and see it so I can troubleshoot why it isn't working.

Comment: In your last example, try replace the word `node` with anything else, `jerdubsPowerShellStep` for example

Comment: For declarative pipelines: when you use `def msg = ...` you have to put it in `script { ... }`.

Comment: @MarioR. thanks, I tried that and it works.